# How can I hide my IP from linux who command

Tags: security, ip, who

I am a Linux system admin, I will login every system of my local network. I don't want my IP to show up via who command. 
For example, if someone enters:

```
$ who
```

it reveals my IP. Is there any way to hide my IP from the who Linux command?

[EDIT by chrips]

This is important for those concerned with their personal utility servers being hacked! Obviously, you would want to hide your current home IP from an attacker lest they find a vector on you!

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you also admin on the systems where you want to login?

Comment: Iam the admin of my lan, I have responsibilty to monitor employees

Comment: @SuperKrish You are also accountable. It would be a bit hard to track down  the responsible person if there are no tracks left behind. What is the _problem_ you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Kusalananda , they user find my ip and they do dos(ping of death) on my system. This is the problem iam trying to solve. Iam not able to block the ping port because of some reason

Comment: @SuperKrish It sound like the problem is how to properly configure the firewall to protect from DOS attacks rather than how to hide your IP. Also, if one or several of your users misbehaves, I'd assume that you have some form of strategy in place for dealing with them. This may be a social issue rather than a technical one.

Comment: @SuperKrish Actually... if the employees you're responsible for monitoring are launching DoS attacks on your machine—that sounds like a question for [workplace.se], your HR department, and/or the police.

Comment: From all your comments, it sounds like you're trying to solve some bigger problem than just hiding an IP address in `who`. At minimum, you want to also hide it in finger, netstat, ss, no doubt various files in `/proc`, etc. Please describe the problem you actually need to solve, including what you need to monitor. There are some approaches that I think will work, such as namespaces (containers), auditd, and automated monitoring systems, but hard to know for sure without fully understanding the requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most simply you could make the utmp log files non-world readable. This is even mentioned in the *utmp man page*:

> Unlike various other systems, where utmp logging can be disabled by removing the file, **utmp must always exist** on Linux.  If you want to disable who(1) then do **not** make utmp world **readable**.

like this:

```
sudo chmod go-r /var/log/wtmp /var/run/utmp
who        # shows nothing, not even an error!
sudo who   # still works for root
rudi     :0           2017-04-18 19:08 (console)
```

So this would disable `who` completely, not only skip IP addresses.

**Another idea** (maybe a bit silly) to hide only the IPs could be to let your ssh server listen at another port (1234) and on localhost only. Then run a "proxy" (socat, netcat) to forward from public_ip:22 to localhost:1234:

1. change ssh server config, /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

   Port 1234
2. run a proxy on ssh server machine:

   socat TCP-LISTEN:22,fork TCP:localhost:1234

Now all utmp logs (`who`, `last`) will show the same and useless localhost IP.

**Note** maybe your users could still see the real connections via `netstat`. Instead of the userspace proxy (`socat`) you could also setup `iptables` NAT and MASQUERADING rules for the incomming ssh traffic. Or you could always use an extra "ssh hop" to always login from the same IP. This is left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: @rudimeter I want to hide my ip, Your idea not related to this. Please explain how to place rules in iptables.It doesnot hide anything

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @SuperKrish you _can't_ hide your IP. You can stop the entry being written into - or read from - `/etc/?tmp` but users can still run `netstat -na` and look for (say) sessions landing on port 22 (ssh). This "silly idea" attempts to obfuscate inbound sessions by having them land on a different port, and then redirecting that port to the true port. Remote sessions are then added into `/etc/?tmp` as coming from `localhost` rather than from your true IP address.

Comment: @rudimeter Thanks, It very useful. Is there any possibilites to hide ip from netstat

Answer (score 2):

The `who` utility parses the data in the `/var/run/utmp` database.  This database is updated by `login` when you log into the system (and by a number of other utilities too, see `man utmp`), and the data is recorded persistently in `/var/log/wtmp` if that file exists.

These records are useful in tracking down why and when a system might have crashed or started to misbehave, and should not be modified.

So the answer is: You can't without modifying the behaviour of `who` or of the programs that write to `/var/run/utmp` and `/var/log/wtmp`, or by modifying these (binary) files yourself.  And you shouldn't as this would potentially make the system 1) insecure and 2) hard to diagnose in the case of malfunction.

Comment: I should be possible to change the permissions of the utmp file so that users can't read it.

Comment: @rudimeier Yes, that would achieve the goal of hiding the admin's IP, but it would also render the `who` utility useless for _all_ other purposes.

Comment: maybe the admin could provide a patched ```who``` SUID binary which does not print IPs.

Comment: @rudimeier ... and that's what I referred to when I said it may render the system insecure.  Just making random system binaries SUID is _not_ a good idea. You would additionally need do the same with `w` and any other utility that needs to parse `utmp`.

Comment: You'd need to consider all the other tools and utilities that use `wtmp`, and then you'd need to fix up `netstat` and friends. Suddenly this sounds rather like a rootkit...

Comment: @roaima do you know how to hide ip from netstat